# How to preserve the original type of a type-variable in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following example:

```
class bounds
{
  private StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

  public <Type> void add (Type value)
  {
    add_specific (value);
    str.append (String.format("%n"));
  }

  private <Type extends Number> void add_specific (Type value)
  {
    str.append (value);
  }

  public String toString () { return str.toString(); }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    bounds test = new bounds();
    test.add (new Integer (42));
    System.out.print (test.toString());
  }
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
bounds.java:7: error: method add_specific in class bounds cannot be applied to given types;
    add_specific (value);
    ^
  required: Type#1
  found: Type#2
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Type#2
    bound(s): Number
  where Type#1,Type#2 are type-variables:
    Type#1 extends Number declared in method add_specific(Type#1)
    Type#2 extends Object declared in method add(Type#2)
1 error
```

This looks to me as if the original type of the argument passed to the `add` method gets lost in the body of `add`. How can I preserve the type so that the correct `add_specific` method can be chosen?

**Update**

I have simplified my example, because I thought it would be easier to understand. But it seems to me that most people do not understand the reason why it contains a generic and a specific function. So I paste a more advanced example. Maybe this makes the reasons more obvious:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class bounds
{
  private StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

  public <Type> void add (Type value)
  {
    add_specific (value);
    str.append (String.format("%n"));
  }

  private <Type extends Number> void add_specific (Type value)
  {
    str.append (value);
  }

  private void add_specific (String value)
  {
    str.append ('"');
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
      char ch = value.charAt(i);
      switch (ch) {
      case '\\': str.append ("\\\\"); break;
      case '"': str.append ("\\\""); break;
      default: str.append (ch);
      }
    }
    str.append ('"');
  }

  private static DateFormat iso8601
    = new SimpleDateFormat("'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'\"'");

  private void add_specific (Date date)
  {
    str.append (iso8601.format(date));
  }

  public String toString ()
  {
    return str.toString();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    bounds test = new bounds();

    test.add (new Integer (42));
    test.add ("42");
    test.add (new Date());

    System.out.print (test.toString());
  }
}
```

I have a generic function called `add`. This generic function does something generic and calls a specific function to do something specific. The problem is, that the type to select the specific function gets lost in the generic function. And the question is how to fix this? How do I have to write the generic function so that it is still possible to select the right specific function in the body of the generic function?

Comment: Whenever you name a class starting with a lower-case letter, a kitten dies. Please don't do that.

Comment: @wolfcastle Do they care about kitties nowadays at Castle Wolfenstein?

Answer (score 3):

> This looks to me as if the original type of the argument passed to the add method gets lost in the body of `add`.

Well, type erasure means that `Type` won't be known at execution time, but that's not the immediate reason you're getting a compile-time error. You can call `add` with *any* type - whereas you can only call `add_specific` with a type which is compatible with `Number`. So for example, consider:

```
// TODO: Fix your naming to meet Java naming conventions
bounds b = new bounds();
b.<String>add("foo");
```

How would you expect that to call `add_specific`? `String` doesn't extend `Number`.

(As an aside, it's also a *really* bad idea to name a type parameter `Type` - it's too easy to confuse it with `java.lang.reflect.Type`.)

Options:

- Add the `extends Number` bound to `Type` in `add`
- Remove the bound from `Type` in `add_specific`

EDIT: Okay, so it sounds like you'd only given us half the picture - you're expecting overload resolution to be performed at execution time based on `Type`. That's not going to work, for two reasons:

- Java *always* performs overload resolution at compile-time
- Type erasure means that the information isn't present at execution time to base an overload decision on anyway. If you want that information, you'll need another parameter of type `Class<Type>`.

Comment: LOL your answers are always funny. I did it that way, because this was my intention to do so. I have a generic function doing something generic and calling a specific function doing something specific. The specific function exists because there is more than one specific function. If there would be only one specific function, the job of the function would not be specific. So it is neither an option to make the generic function specific not to do the specific function generic. And it is of course no problem to add an additional catching method for strings and anything else.

Comment: @ceving: I don't see what's "funny" about this at all... but your approach to this simply won't work, and it's not clear why you *expected* it to work. You're not really using the fact that your method is generic at all - your `add` method might as well be `public void add(Object obj)`.

Comment: Yes I have removed all the other specific methods, because I thought this would be easier to understand. But it seems to be wrong.

Comment: @ceving: Oh, so your code wasn't actually representative to start with? That really doesn't help us to help you. But if you were expecting the compiler to pick an appropriate overload at execution time based on `Type`, then again you'll be disappointed. That's simply not how Java works. At execution time `Type` won't even be known due to type erasure.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the other specific functions.

Comment: What do you mean with execution time? I have called the generic with a string, a number and a date. They are all known at compile time.

Comment: @ceving: I mean "when the code executes". You know the type at compile-time, but there's no concept of checking `Type` when the code is actually running. It looks like the right answer for you here would be to just have multiple overloads of `add`, and make each one call a common method for what they have in common.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
public <Type> void add (Type value)
{
   add_specific (value);
   ...
}
```

`add_specific` requires the value to be of a type that extends `Number` but `add` doesn't require/ensure that. Hence the error.

To fix it, you'd need to change `add` to use `<Type extends Number>`, but I doubt that's what you want. It seems like a design error to me: `add_specific` should call the more generic looking `add` and not the other way round.

Btw, as John Skeet already said, please adhere to the coding conventions, which will make it easer to spot bugs and read your code.

Comment: It is no option to make the generic function specific, because it would not be generic any more.

Comment: @ceving that's what I meant with 'design error', the specific should call the generic one.

Comment: Is this a general Java limitation that a generic can only be called by a specific?

Comment: @ceving in the context of my answer that's not a limit in the language itself but rather a general design issue. However, your update changes that since you actually seem to have something different in mind.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler is screaming because reference `value` in your `add` method is not necessarily a `Number`

to solve this :

change `add` method to :

```
public <Type extends Number> void add (Type value)
{

}
```

or add :

```
public <Type> void add (Type value)
  {
    if (value instanceof Number){
        add_specific ((Number)value);
        str.append (String.format("%n"));
    }
  }
```

Comment: No that is not the problem. The problem is, that the type gets erased in `add`. And the question is how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the add and add_specific methods, and just overload the add method.
Beware, however, that the choice of which method to make is done ***statically at compile time***, NOT dynamically at runtime.

Like Jon said, what you are trying to do won't work. If you want all client code to look the same, then do something like this; although in Effective Java, Bloch suggests you avoid this kind of confusing API.

```
class Bounds {   
   private StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

  private void appendNewline() {
       str.append (String.format("%n"));
  }
  public  void add (Number value)   {
    str.append (value);   
    appendNewline();
  }

  public void add (String value)   {
    str.append ('"');
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
      char ch = value.charAt(i);
      switch (ch) {
      case '\\': str.append ("\\\\"); break;
      case '"': str.append ("\\\""); break;
      default: str.append (ch);
      }
    }
    str.append ('"');  
  appendNewline();
 }

  private static DateFormat iso8601
    = new SimpleDateFormat("'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ'\"'");

  public void add (Date date)   {
    str.append (iso8601.format(date));   
    appendNewline();
  }

  public String toString ()   {
    return str.toString();   }

  public static void main (String[] args)   {
    bounds test = new bounds();

    test.add (new Integer (42));
    test.add ("42");
    test.add (new Date());

    System.out.print (test.toString());   } 
}
```

Comment: You have removed the thing the generic is doing. You code does not the same as my code.

Comment: @ceving I added back in the missing functionality.

Comment: Yes a pretty ugly hack of redundant code. Doing something generic belongs in a generic function. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: BTW my example is fully static. Every type is known at compile time. There are no dynamic types at all. The string and the number are literals. So I have no idea what do you mean with "runtime".